# How reset rotating with scaling context?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Example with Fabric.js:

http://jsfiddle.net/regsmile/jD7T4/58/

```
// how reset rotate with scale ? I dont' know

var itemS=new fabric.Rect();
itemS.set({originX:'left',originY:'top',width:50,height:50,left:145,top:135, fill: '#E14B17',hasControls:false,selectable:false,angle:30,scaleX:1.5});
canvas.add(itemS);

itemS.clipTo = function (ctx)
{
      ctx.save();
    // how reset rotate with scale ?
      ctx.rotate((this.angle* -1) * (Math.PI / 180));   
      ctx.rect((-this.width/2),(-this.height/2),this.width,this.height);    
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.renderAll();
```

last item, keep a scaling but how reset ?